# SpriteKit - Getting The Weight Of A SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have an app with large boxes falling on top of the small red box. I would like to know when the small red block reaches a certain weight (X blocks are resting on top of it). I couldn't find a weight property for the red block. Any suggestions? [image: Screenshot]

**EDIT:** Just to clarify. The boxes falling from the top will be random sizes, and falling from random positions. So there isn't really a way to keeping track of what landed on top of the red block. I need some way to measure the downward force being applied to the red block

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted (?), because it's a pretty interesting question! Maybe try applying [a force](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/mass) to your blocks. Then the mass of your red block should increase (I think you have to set the "affectedByGravity" property to true). Cannot test anything right now, but I think the solution lies in SKPhysicsBody

Comment: mass shouldn't be affected by gravity, otherwise you would be saying that the mass of an object on earth is different than the mass of an object on the moon.  @StackOverflower, I do not think that the built in physics calculates weight for you, you may have to do that manually (node.mass * gravity), then apply the amount of force the other blocks on top of it are applying to the block.  For your scenario with the tilted block, you may have to figure out how much of the tilted block mass is actually on the red block

Comment: Is the physics engine sophisticated enough that you could apply an upwards force on the red block and gradually increase this until it starts to move?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the weight for each node the following way and then add them together.

```
redBox.PhysicsBody?.mass
```

Comment: The big blocks will be falling from random postitions above, so some might not land on the red block.

Comment: Just check if there is a collision between the falling block and the red block.

Comment: That wouldn't work if a big block tipped over and was halfway on the red block